# Removing axes numbering

Tags: plotting

I have the following example where I want to see the numbering only of the left y axis and the bottom x axis. The `FrameTicks`should be the same for the both x axes and separately for the both y axes. How can I do that?

```
data1 = Get@"https://pastebin.com/raw/2bswYsFT";
data2 = Get@"https://pastebin.com/raw/wApReeNB";

symbolPlusBlue = 
  Graphics[{Blue, Line[{{{-1, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}}}]}];
symbolCrossRed = 
  Graphics[{Red, Line[{{{-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}}]}];

ListPlot[{data1, data2}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{symbolPlusBlue, 0.1}, {symbolCrossRed, 0.1}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1500, 1600}, {370, 820}}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{1500, 1550, 1600}, {1500, 1550, 1600}}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, {"x", ""}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
   FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{1500, 1550, 1600}, {{1500, ""}, {1550, ""}, {1600, ""}}}}
```

The second part for the top now specifies the label to be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the option `FrameStyle` with the following setting:

```
FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, FontOpacity -> 0}}
```

[image]